# Create ID with this [0-9A-Za-z$&#@] [0-9A-Za-z$&#@]*

Tags: antlr4

I creat this syntax:

```
val: ID;
ID: [0-9A-Za-z$&#@][0-9A-Za-z$&#@]*
```

When I give a value for example 'A' or '&X' in test I got this error:

> val:1:0: mismatched input '&X' expecting ID
>
> val:1:0: mismatched input 'A' expecting ID

Answer (score 0):

As both parts of ID are identical change it to [0-9A-Za-z$&#@]+ Can you please provide code whole grammar. As far as I can see it is correct. Please provide more info.

Comment: This the complete grammar:  
`COMMENT: LINECOMMENT3 ( ~[?\r\n] ~[\r\n]* )* ;`  
`ID: [A-Z0-9_$@#.] [A-Z0-9_$@#.]*;`   
`val: ID;`

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem I have used this syntax:

```
IDX
: 
ID +
;

ID
:
  '#' | '&' | '$' | '.' | '?'| '*' | 'à' | '£' | '@' | [0-9A-Za-z] 
;
```